# Do bonus coin powers include territories controlled by races in decline?

Tags: small-world

Some of the special powers give bonus coins based on regions you "occupy at turn end." Does this include regions controlled by your previous race that has gone into decline?

For example, if you have a race in decline that occupies two forest regions and your current active race has the Forest power, do you get two additional coins for the forest regions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**,

Each race is separate.  In this case you would not get the additional coins for forests controlled by the race in decline.

From the [rules](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_en.pdf), page 5

> The Regions these In Decline tokens occupy also each contribute
>   1 Victory coin to the player; Though the Race banner and Special
>   Power benefits no longer contribute any bonus coins, unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise in said Race or Special Power benefit.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question.  As I read that rule it is talking about the race banner and special power of the race that went into decline.  I was thinking about a situation where your current active race has a bonus power that covers territories controlled by your race in decline.

Comment: Ah, but as I re-read the rules, the graphic on page 5 demonstrates exactly the situations I was concerned with!